# Javascript pressing the button in an interval

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a submit button, which sends the value with POST method to the same page.

```
<button id="log" class="btn bg-purple" formmethod=post value="2" name="start" formaction=start_server.php>Get Log</button>
```

When I press that button, I get the log from the file in a list using PHP. 
[image: Screenshot]

What I want to do now is to make a script with javascript to automatically press the "Get Log" button to reload the log file every 2 seconds so I can have an interactive log, without pressing the button myself.

I have tried this script, but only the alert is working I guess, since it doesn't reload the log file at all.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload=function(){
    var auto = setTimeout(function(){ autoRefresh(); }, 100);

    function submitform(){
      alert('test');
      document.button["log"].submit();
  }

  function autoRefresh(){
     clearTimeout(auto);
     auto = setTimeout(function(){ submitform(); autoRefresh(); }, 2000);
     }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Change `setTimeout(function(){ autoRefresh(); }, 100);` to `setInterval(function(){ autoRefresh(); }, 2000);`.

Comment: I have tried it, no changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your script with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // this handles the click on yout "Get log" button
    $("#log").click(function(){
        //alert('test');
        console.log("Click function");
        $("#log").submit();
    });


    // This sets an interval to simulate a click every 2 seconds.
    auto = setInterval(function(){
        console.log("Interval iteration");
        $("#log").click(); 
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: That doesn't even alert. I enabled jQuery in header.

Comment: If still don't work, try to change your button as I suggest. and notice the `.parent()` I added in the script.

Comment: It worked before the last edit, so you can revert it. Sorry for not accepting it before, was fixing a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Give an ID to your form and replace this line -

```
document.button["log"].submit();
```

With this -

```
document.getElementById('formID').submit();
```